# Application crashing after 10 second or executing "renderInContext" 12 or more times

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I am using the following code to convert HTML to PDF.

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(self.filePath, CGRectZero, nil);    //creating PDF

    int i = 0;
    for (; i < pages; i++)
    {
        if (pageHeight * (i+1) > height)
        {
            CGRect f = [myWebPage frame];
            f.size.height -= (((i+1) * pageHeight) - height);
            [myWebPage setFrame: f];
        }
        // Specify the size of the pdf page
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, width, pageHeight), nil);
        CGContextRef currentContext =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [[[myWebPage subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, pageHeight * i) animated:NO];
        [myWebPage.layer renderInContext: currentContext];
        NSLog(@"I = %d",i);
    }

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
[[[myWebPage subviews] lastObject] setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
[myWebPage setFrame:origframe];
```

but the loop is getting crashed after 10 second or for i >= 12,

its getting crashed at :

```
 [myWebPage.layer renderInContext: currentContext];
```

i have tried with "CGContextRelease(currentContext);" also but its not working..

May I please know why is it crashing and how to prevent crashing of app.

Console output:

```
2013-06-06 10:15:26.179 app[8084:907] Width : 980.000000
2013-06-06 10:15:26.180 app[8084:907] NUMBER OF PAGES : 15
2013-06-06 10:15:26.382 app[8084:907] I = 0
2013-06-06 10:15:28.400 app[8084:907] I = 1
2013-06-06 10:15:28.903 app[8084:907] I = 2
2013-06-06 10:15:30.330 app[8084:907] I = 3
2013-06-06 10:15:31.524 app[8084:907] I = 4
2013-06-06 10:15:32.641 app[8084:907] I = 5
2013-06-06 10:15:33.470 app[8084:907] I = 6
2013-06-06 10:15:34.634 app[8084:907] I = 7
2013-06-06 10:15:35.791 app[8084:907] I = 8
2013-06-06 10:15:36.970 app[8084:907] I = 9
2013-06-06 10:15:38.108 app[8084:907] I = 10
2013-06-06 10:15:38.927 app[8084:907] I = 11
```

and app getting crashed in iPhone (Working properly in simulator )

(UPDATED) :
and in other case its showing :

```
2013-06-06 11:17:33.023 app[8202:907] Width : 320.000000
2013-06-06 11:17:33.024 app[8202:907] NUMBER OF PAGES : 2
2013-06-06 11:17:38.200 app[8202:907] I = 0
2013-06-06 11:17:41.390 app[8202:907] I = 1
2013-06-06 11:17:44.028 app[8202:2103] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main    run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
(lldb)
```

and

```
 libsystem_kernel.dylib`mach_msg_trap:
 0x3aa45e1c:  mov    r12, sp
 0x3aa45e20:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r8}
 0x3aa45e24:  ldm    r12, {r4, r5, r6}
 0x3aa45e28:  mvn    r12, #30
 0x3aa45e2c:  svc    #128
 0x3aa45e30:  pop    {r4, r5, r6, r8}  <=== Thread 1: singal SIGSTOP
 0x3aa45e34:  bx     lr
```

Please help me out..

Comment: What is the error? Which line of code is the crash coming from?

Comment: the app is getting crash..

Comment: its getting crashed at "[myWebPage.layer renderInContext: currentContext];"..

Comment: Yes, we know your app is crashing. But you need to provide more details about the crash. What error appears in the console? If you run your app from Xcode, what does the stack trace show?

Comment: You should see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @rmaddy : please find the above updated question..

Comment: If you restrict your loop to only a few cycles do you get what you wanted. It's not a solution just an experiment to see if your code is doing what it should prior to crashing

Comment: @Warren Burton: ya if the cycle is less then 11 then the application will not crash..

Comment: also interesting is the `webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:` delegate blocking . What is your webview delegate doing with that method. Are you implementing it at all?

Comment: i didn't get yous question..

Comment: Make your PDF in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` Method.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is blocking the main thread for too long.  The iOS watchdog process will kill your app with exception 0x8badfood  when the main thread does not respond to the watchdog for 10 seconds.

You need to break the work up into pieces so the main thread gets time to talk to the iOS every 8 or 9 seconds. Or move work to other threads.

Comment: i tried breaking it in 2 for loops.. each of 10 iterations.. but its still crashing.. can u please suggest or give some sample code according to the above code?

Comment: You've got to return from the function in under 10 seconds so the UIApplication gets control again.  You can't just break up the loop, you've got to give up control.

Answer (score 0):

A `WebView` has a delegate protocol `frameLoadDelegate` which conforms to `WebFrameLoadDelegate`

One of the methods that you may implement is

`- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame`

Your crash is showing

> 2013-06-06 11:17:44.028 app[8202:2103] void
>   SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10
>   seconds. main    run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Which indicates perhaps theres an issue with the default implementation

You may wish to set your `frameLoadDelegate` on `myWebPage` to SomeArbitraryObject (maybe the object which owns myWebPage ) and implement that method as empty

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
{
//nothing to see here, move along
}
```